# How to scrape a website with mulitple pages and the links inside into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to get the data from every firm in the following link with all the contents inside the link. I need each companies data to be in a row. The problem that I am having is that I am not sure how to do that exactly. I don't know which approach to take and from where to begin.

Here is the website: https://www.adgm.com/public-registers/fsra

I have tried to get the information into my code at least and try printing it from the IDE but I have failed and I don't understand why.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.adgm.com/public-registers/fsra")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')
table  = soup.find_all('.every-accord')

for element in table:
    print(element.text)
```

Here's the code that I have been trying. Each table row is in a class "every-accord" which I am trying to get. It is not giving me any errors, but I am not getting any results either.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Pandas has a function ‘read_html’ which will read every table from a page into a dataframe.  (If there is mor Ethan one table you’ll get an array (or dictionary, I don’t recall which)

Comment: @MichaelD I have attempted to do that, though it sadly did not work. The solution provided by @/Ajax1234 did work. However, I am getting the column names in the as part of the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the container:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.adgm.com/public-registers/fsra').text, 'html.parser')
results = [[c.text for c in i.find_all('div', {'class':'col-sm-6'})]+[i.a['href'], i.find('div', {'class':'col-lg-5'}).text] for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':'every-accord'})]
no_headers = [[i for i in c[1:] if i not in {'Company Status', 'Address'}] for c in results]
```

Output:

```
[['160024', 'Active', 'Level 7, Al Sila Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/aarna-capital-limited', 'Aarna Capital Limited'], ['160007', 'Active', 'Unit 8, 6th floor Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Markets Square, Al Maryah Island Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates P.O. Box 764605', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/aberdeen-asset-middle-east-limited', 'Aberdeen Asset Middle East Limited'], ['180041', 'Active', 'Floor 22, Al Sila Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/abu-dhabi-catalyst-partners-limited', 'Abu Dhabi Catalyst Partners Limited'], ['180021', 'Active', 'Unit 5, 6th Floor, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ad-global-investors-limited', 'AD Global Investors Limited'], ['180039', 'Active', '3419, 34th Floor, Al Maqam Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ad-investment-management-limited', 'AD Investment Management Limited'], ['170036', 'Active', '10th Floor, Al Sila Tower, ADGM Square, Al Maryah Island', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcb-asset-management-ltd', 'ADCB Asset Management Ltd.'], ['160006', 'Active', 'Level 34, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcm-altus-investment-management-limited', 'ADCM Altus Investment Management Limited'], ['160005', 'Active', '33rd floor, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcorp-ltd', 'ADCORP Ltd'], ['180024', 'Active', 'Unit 10, Level 6, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adnoc-reinsurance-limited', 'ADNOC Reinsurance Limited'], ['170025', 'Active', 'Office 712, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ads-investment-solutions-limited', 'ADS Investment Solutions Limited']]
```

Edit: formatting columns from `results`:

```
new_results = [{**{j[i]:j[i+1] for i in range(0, len(j), 2)}, **{'link':a, 'name':b}} for *j, a, b in results]
```

Output:

```
[{'Financial Services Permission Number': '160024', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Level 7, Al Sila Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/aarna-capital-limited', 'name': 'Aarna Capital Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '160007', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Unit 8, 6th floor Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Markets Square, Al Maryah Island Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates P.O. Box 764605', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/aberdeen-asset-middle-east-limited', 'name': 'Aberdeen Asset Middle East Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '180041', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Floor 22, Al Sila Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/abu-dhabi-catalyst-partners-limited', 'name': 'Abu Dhabi Catalyst Partners Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '180021', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Unit 5, 6th Floor, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ad-global-investors-limited', 'name': 'AD Global Investors Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '180039', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': '3419, 34th Floor, Al Maqam Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ad-investment-management-limited', 'name': 'AD Investment Management Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '170036', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': '10th Floor, Al Sila Tower, ADGM Square, Al Maryah Island', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcb-asset-management-ltd', 'name': 'ADCB Asset Management Ltd.'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '160006', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Level 34, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcm-altus-investment-management-limited', 'name': 'ADCM Altus Investment Management Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '160005', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': '33rd floor, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adcorp-ltd', 'name': 'ADCORP Ltd'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '180024', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Unit 10, Level 6, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/adnoc-reinsurance-limited', 'name': 'ADNOC Reinsurance Limited'}, {'Financial Services Permission Number': '170025', 'Company Status': 'Active', 'Address': 'Office 712, Al Khatem Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 'link': '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/ads-investment-solutions-limited', 'name': 'ADS Investment Solutions Limited'}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped. One comment though, if you don't mind, I am getting the output in this format <br/>      ['Financial Services Permission Number', '160024', 'Company Status', 'Active', 'Address', 'Level 7, Al Sila Tower, Abu Dhabi Global Market Square, Al Maryah Island, Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', '/public-registers/fsra/fsf/aarna-capital-limited', 'Aarna Capital Limited'] Do you have any idea I can make every even column in to a column name for the row after it? Sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: @MaqAlmulla Glad to help! Please see my recent edit, as I added a solution to transform the lists of lists into a list of dictionaries, with each column name being associated with its proper value.